# size of objects in python 3

Tags: python, object, size

```
class test:
    x = []
    def __init__(self, n):
        x = list(range(n))

z=test(500)
sys.getsizeof(z)
56

sys.getsizeof(z.x)
4608
```

This is not consistent. I need to compute the size of an object I created. How do I do that?

Comment: You can't.  Objects don't necessarily have unique owners.

Comment: `x` is a local variable in `__init__`, so `z.x` is `[]`.

Comment: What do you mean *"not consistent"*? The size of `z` doesn't include the size of `x` because `z` just contains a *reference* to the list (which may also be referenced elsewhere).

Comment: So if I need to know how much memory I need to instantiate a new object with all new internal objects, I have to add up all the sizes of any internal objects, recursively if need be? Seems like a lot of work!

Comment: @Bing Bang I use this code to know the size of any object recursively: [link](https://goshippo.com/blog/measure-real-size-any-python-object/)